# Self-container close-able full screen modal overlay for existing webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css

Please forgive me for not including any code, but I always struggle with front-end. I have found numerous blogs and how-to's for putting up a full-screen modal display, but all of them have disrupted my site's existing css or JavaScript in some way, some how. Can anyone point me to a simple, self-contained example that is guaranteed to be a drop-in solution for a website that already has its own things going on?

Answer (score 0):

I googled full screen modal and [found this](http://joaopereirawd.github.io/animatedModal.js/). As close to a drop in solution as you could ask for I imagine. You'll need to download their lib though.

Taken from their site:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.2.0/animate.min.css">
</head>


<body>
    <!--Call your modal-->
    <a id="demo01" href="#animatedModal">DEMO01</a>

    <!--DEMO01-->
    <div id="animatedModal">
        <!--THIS IS IMPORTANT! to close the modal, the class name has to match the name given on the ID  class="close-animatedModal" -->
        <div class="close-animatedModal"> 
            CLOSE MODAL
        </div>

        <div class="modal-content">
              <!--Your modal content goes here-->
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="yourPath/animatedModal.min.js"></script>

<script>
    //This is your script
    $("#demo01").animatedModal();
</script>
```